# Why is sprintf working in one example and not the next?

Tags: c, string, integer, printf, output

Here's the code I have:

```
time_t tim=time(NULL);                        // acquire time information
struct tm * now=localtime(&tim);

char cyear[3], cmonth[2], cday[2], chour[2], cmin[2];           
int test = 13;
sprintf(cyear, "%d", test);
sprintf(cmonth, "%d", now->tm_mon+1);
sprintf(cday, "%d", now->tm_mday);
sprintf(chour, "%d", now->tm_hour);
sprintf(cmin, "%d", now->tm_min);

printf("cyear is: %s\n",cyear);
printf("cmin is: %s\n",cmin);
```

The output I get is:

```
cyear is:

cmin is: 7
```

The output also won't work for cmonth or cday, but chour and cmin seem to give a correct output. What's going on here?

Comment: You're not leaving room for the terminating NUL character.

Comment: Avoid using `sprintf`; *always* use `snprintf`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cmonth` version will cause a buffer overflow if it is October, November or December. `cday` will buffer overflow if it's the 10th of the month or later, and `chour` will overflow if it is past ten o'clock., and `cmin` will overflow if it is 10 minutes past the hour.

So your code is good for 1 January 1970 00:00 but not a lot else!

To fix this, make your buffers bigger; and also use the `snprintf` function. That will guarantee you get no buffer overflow if the fields do not contain what you expected. For example:

```
char chour[6];
snprintf(chour, sizeof chour, "%d", now->tm_hour);
```

Comment: Using `snprintf` guarantees that you don't get a buffer overflow, but it doesn't guarantee that you get correct results. If you have too short buffers, you *cannot* get the right results. Nevertheless, `snprintf()` is better.